# Cheer and Dance Team SFX collections?

Tags: boutique, sound-libraries, sound-effects-recording

I frequently find myself editing music for dance team and cheerleading performances.  Can anyone recommend a good collection of "Cheer effects" (for lack of a better term)?  Thanks in advance.

Allow me to add a clarification:  Rather than looking for the sounds a cheerleading squad makes, I'm looking for the Sci-Fi style sfx they use to accent choreography in their performances.

Comment: Could be a good boutique series.

Answer (score 4):

If it were me, I would schedule a recording session with a few cheer squads and record my own sets, both interior and exterior. That way you are getting exactly the material you want and need, plus you can reuse for future projects.

If you go that route, be sure to record with multiple mic setups and recorders, getting plenty of variety. And when you are done, be sure to make a donation to either the school or squad as thanks for their time and talent. Oh, and pizza doesn't hurt, either!

Comment: Thanks @Jay.  More to the point, I'm looking for Sci-Fi SFX to add into their performance soundtracks to accent the choreography.  For example, they toss someone into the air with a phaser whirl, then a bang on the catch.

Comment: @Phoenix, ok sorry, my take on your question was totally off. For sounds like that, I'd check any number of commercially available collections (Hollywood Edge, Sound Ideas, etc).